# Why am I receiving a declaration exception?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am running with jasmine 2.0 in VS 2013 with resharper as the test runner.

I have an app.js file:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ["navigation"]);
```

I have included them in my controller:

```
angular.module('navigation', []).controller('NavigationCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.tabs = [
        { title: 'First Tab', content: 'Controllers\FirstTab' }
    ];
});
```

Spec Runner file:

```
<title>Jasmine Spec Runner</title>

<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/Content/jasmine/jasmine_favicon.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/jasmine/jasmine.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jasmine/jasmine.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jasmine/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jasmine/boot.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/angular-mocks.js"></script>


<!-- include source files here... -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/App/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/App/Controllers/NavigationController.js"></script>

<!-- include spec files here... -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JSTests/NavigationControllerTests.js"></script>
```

and then my test:

```
describe("NavigationCtrl", function () {
    var scope;
    var controller;

    beforeEach(module('app', 'navigation'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = $controller('NavigationCtrl', {$scope: scope});
        }));

    it("should contain a list of tabs", function () {
        expect(scope.tabs[0].title).toBe('FirstTab');
    });
});
```

I get the error:

```
 NavigationController encountered a declaration exception
```

I am new to angular and Jasmine testing (not unit testing) and I cannot see what I am missing to make this first test work.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE 1.

Based on comments updated code base

Comment: I see that your controller's name is NavigationCtrl: `angular.module('app').controller('NavigationCtrl', function($scope)`, but in test controller's name is NavigationController: `describe("NavigationController", function () {`

Comment: @alexs I changed that but it didn't make a difference

Comment: try controller = $controller('NavigationCtrl', {
                '$scope': scope
            });

Comment: @rahpuser I replaced that and I am still receiving the same error

Comment: are you sure angular-mocks.js is available in there ? what is you use mocks.module.. and mocks.inject

Comment: @rahpuser it is included in the SpecRunner.cshtml and assuming Resharper uses that file to run the tests yes

Comment: @Owen how would you fix that and still have them in separate files for readability

Comment: The easiest way is to not have the angular declaration in a function.

Comment: @Owen Can I leave it in a file by itself with just:  var app = angular.module('app', []); and no wrapper or anything around it?

Comment: Yes, you can. You need to create a module in your controller file to inject into the main app.

Comment: @Owen same error but Code has been updated in question to the latest version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66040/discussion-between-robert-and-owen).